# What do the different divisor choices signify when calculating priorities?

Tags: algorithms

So I was going through the book Algorithms by Jeff Erickson. In the Huntington-Hill method where we will assign representatives in US states, we calculate the priority for the assignment of next representative. A representative will be assigned based on highest priority for a particular state.

priority = $\frac{P}{\sqrt{r(r+1)}}$

$P$ - population of the state.

$r$ - number of representative already allocated for that state.

In the book, other two methods are also given where priorities are calculates such that $\frac{P}{1+r}$ and $\frac{P}{2r+1}$

For me $\frac{P}{1+r}$ makes most sense as if we have $r = 0$ we simply take the population as the priority and so on as $r$ increases we assign priority by dividing by representative count.

I wanted to know what are benefits of different priorities? When to use one over other?

Comment: $\sqrt{t(r(r+1)}$ also becomes to 1 when $r=0$, meaning that we just use the population. The priorities are just various ways to weigh the fact that some states have representatives already, while others don't. I don't remember this method (and I don't live in the USA so it doesn't matter to me), but in general it pays of to think about extreme situations, in this case it might be two states with one having a population that is more than twice that of the other. The differences are mostly political and the reasons to choose over the other is as a consequence also mostly political.